# How to test a model callback that only works in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I deliberately made my callback only fire on production:

```
after_create :send_slack_notification unless Rails.env.test?

def send_slack_notification
  SlackNotifier.send('test')
end
```

Now I'd like to create a test in RSpec. Is there a way to change the environment for this specific test? The following obviously doesn't work now :(

```
it "sends a slack notification after registration" do
  notifier = double(SlackNotifier)
  expect(notifier).to receive(:send)
  user_create
end
```

Added SlackNotifier class

```
class SlackNotifier
  URI = ENV['SLACK_WEBHOOK']
  CHANNEL = "#channel"
  USERNAME = "Bot"

  def self.message msg, uri: URI, channel: CHANNEL, username: USERNAME
    new(uri, channel:channel, username:username).message(msg)
  end

  def initialize uri = URI, channel: CHANNEL, username: USERNAME
    raise UriNotSetError unless uri
    @client ||= Slack::Notifier.new(uri, channel: channel , username: username)
  end

  def message msg
    @client.ping msg
  end

  class UriNotSetError < StandardError
    def message
      "The URI for the Slack Webhook was not properly configured, make sure you set ENV['SLACK_WEBHOOK']"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you show that SlackNotifier class? sounds like you could just move that `unless Rails.env.test?` line inside the actual method so it does nothing but you can still test it's getting called.

Comment: Also, if you defined a custom `send` method, I would suggest you to change the name to something else, ruby already defines a `send` method.

Comment: Good tip on changing the method name, but I don't understand why you need the SlackNotifier class? It's just a PORO that has it's own Unit test.

Comment: You can set a NoOpHttpClient in your .env for dev and test mode. It's documented in the readme for the gem.

Comment: @bo-oz I asked for the class code just to see where you could put that `unless` condition.

Comment: I added the SlackNotifier class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, is not it?

```
it "sends a slack notification after registration" do
  allow(Rails.env).to receive(:test?).and_return(false)
  notifier = double(SlackNotifier)
  expect(notifier).to receive(:send)
  user_create
end
```

UPDATE: You should fix conditions of Model

```
after_create :send_slack_notification, unless: Proc.new { Rails.env.test? }

def send_slack_notification
  SlackNotifier.send('test')
end
```

Comment: Sounds logical, but unfortunately doesn't work... The after_create callback is still not called.

Comment: Works like a charm! Could you explain the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: @bo-oz It was nice to work. Callback takes block, method and Proc as arguments. Booleans can not be evaluated. So I used `Proc` and changed the return value with `allow` to the return value of `Rails.env.test? `.

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than checking your Rails environment, you can more easily test this behavior with an environment variable. You can make the environment variable the URL for your Slack webhook, and then check for the existence of the variable as the determination of whether or not to attempt to send. When it's not defined, there's a no-op.

thoughtbot has a nice gem to temporarily change an environment variable for a specific test called [climate_control](https://github.com/thoughtbot/climate_control) that makes these kinds of tests easier to set up.